# Azure Function is unreachable

Tags: azure-functions

I'm new to Azure, and I'm working on azure functions right now when I get the following error

> "Azure Functions Runtime is unreachable. Click here for details on storage configuration."

I'd like to know why I'm receiving this error and if there is any documentation that explains how to fix it.

wishing for a positive reaction.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***According to this [Document](https://azurelessons.com/azure-functions-runtime-is-unreachable/) and [Microsoft-Documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-recover-storage-account) it says,***

> We need to check the storage account we are mentioning exists.
> It should be accessible by your FunctionApp which you are using.
> We need to make sure if quota of execution is not full
> And also check Firewall configuration